# What is the easiest way to strip HTML from scraped web data so that I am only left with strings of words?

Tags: web-scraping, nlp, data-cleaning

I am interested in collecting a large corpus of text from various websites. The result will have lots of html. Is there an easy way of getting rid of the HTML so that I am left with only strings of words which I can then analyse?

I don't mind paying, but I prefer free and fast tools.

I have had a look and it looks like you can do this manually using packages like beautiful soup in python or using paid services like import.io to automatically clean data as the scraping occurs.

But are there better tools avaliable for stripping html from raw text?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) in my project to extract text from websites, it is simple to use, and i have used [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)
for clicking buttons in website to load more data.

Answer (score -1):

ruby and the nokogiri gem (library) are probably a good place to start.  You mentioned python but did not tag it so I am asume you are not set on python.

Crawling around websites, following links and getting all text is fairly straightforward, nokogiri has a .text method that does this.  In probability you want to do a little hand coding for each site to refine what you get.  I'me parsing music listing sites and am averaging around 20 lines of unique code per site.

I should mention is that you should first see if there is some type of XLM/RSS feed, these are a lot easier to process than the web content.  nokogiri can help you with this.